# Getting an empty array out of function when using callback

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to access some arrays outside of the function but initially, it was just an empty array.
That's why I  tried using the callback in the function but that didn't change anything.

```
function liveGames(callback){

  instance.numGames(function(error, result) {
    for(var i = 0; i<result; i++){
      instance.getName(i, function(error, result2) {
        if ((!result2[1]) || (result2[0]==="")) return;
        var newOption = document.createElement("option");
        newOption.text = (result2[0] + " (" + result2[2]*0.000000000000000001);
        newOption.value = result2[7];
        document.getElementById("slct1").add(newOption);
        optionArrayCon.push(result2);
        betArray = optionArrayCon;
        callback && callback();
        console.log(optionArrayCon);
        console.log(betArray);
      });
    }
  });

}

console.log(betArray);
var opt2 = [];
var opt = betArray[0];
 opt2.push(opt[0]);
 console.log(opt2);
```

Comment: Where are you calling the `liveGames` function?

Comment: What are you expect 'callback && callback();' to do?

Comment: If you want to pass the array to the callback, you need to pass the array to the callback, which `callback && callback();` isn't doing. That would be `callback && callback(betArray);`. (But you need to declare `betArray`, currently your code is falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).)

Comment: @MichaelAlexanderMontero the liveGames function is being called in a js file elsewhere. This code is in the main webpage